# Table with column of a certain width

Tags: tables, columns

I'm trying to make a table with a column of a certain width. Using basic `{tabular}` and the `p` parameter creates column of the given width plus some extra millimeters (for example `p{50mm}` leads to width of about 55 mm when printed). When I try `{tabularx}` and add a specific width for the whole table, it works just fine, without any added width on print (so I guess the problem probably isn’t in printer settings).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{50mm}|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        1&2&3&4&5\\
        \hline
        1&2&3&4&5\\
        \hline
        1&2&3&4&5\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to subtract the column separator from your length.

[image: column separator]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr 50mm-2\tabcolsep}|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        1&2&3&4&5\\
        \hline
        1&2&3&4&5\\
        \hline
        1&2&3&4&5\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```